# Get current drive letter in CMD

Tags: shell, cmd

When using CMD you can get the driveletter like this:

```
%cd~0,2%
```

But when echo off, this won't work

```
@echo off
echo %cd~0,2%
```

The output is

> EHCO is off.

Anyway to get the current drive letter without echo on?

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `%PWD~0,2%` or something? Also, does `%HOMEDRIVE%` work?

Comment: Oh wow %HOMEDRIVE% worked, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The correct statement is

```
echo %cd:~0,2%
```

note the <kbd>:</kbd>

%homedrive% won't work properly in this rôle. `%cd% is the **current** drive,

Comment: There’s a difference, but does anyone know what said role is?

Comment: @minitech well, who knows what OP actually wants? I took my cue from the statement in the question, `Anyway to get the current drive letter without echo on?` So I presume that it's the **current drive** that's required. Only on systems that have just one drive will that necessarily be the same as the **home drive**.

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly %HOMEDRIVE% works, many thanks to [minitech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech)